# What is the best toolchain to build & test &deploy cosmwasm contract to terra netweork?

Tags: blockchain, toolchain, terra-blockchain

I am developing smart contracts on terra network.
I am bored and sick of building them using dirty docker commands.
I am using houston for toolchain but it doesn't seem to work well.
Is there any better toolchain to build, test, deploy cosmwasm contracts with just one single command?

Comment: The industry is changing fast. They now have a CLI tool called Terrain as part of the getting started documentation. https://docs.terra.money/docs/develop/dapp/quick-start/README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there is no such toolchain yet.

I am a Terra smart contract developer using the skills you mentioned and going through the process you meant in every-day-basis.
Unfortunately, I also could not found the answer for toolchain which makes development easy for developers.

But, if you take the partial optimization into the account, you can do that!

For example, you can build bash script for both building and testing(unit & integration-test) the Rust-written smart contracts, since they are related with `cargo ...` commands.

About the deployment and testing smart contracts on terra network, you can also build script using Terra SDK(.js or .py). For the convenience, you select the testnet since LocalTerra needs manual start. That script illustrates the deploy and interact procedure in order.

Surely, it is not the best answer, just improvement advice from my personal experience.